# How do i repeat this game until ur_choice() >=0

Tags: c

i want to repeat this game until user enters a invalid input other than r/R , p/P or s/S
i created the ur_choice function so that i can get a negative value in case a wrong input is submitted now how do i loop this ur_choice() function until it returns -1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int ur_choice(){
    printf ("choose r/R for Rock p/P for Paper s/S for Scissor : ");
    char choice = getchar();
    if (choice == 'r' || choice == 'R')
        return 0;
    if (choice == 'p' || choice == 'P')
        return 1;
    if (choice == 's' || choice == 'S')
        return 2;
    else{
        return -1;
    }     
}
int pc_choice(){
    srand(time(0));
    int random = rand() % 3;
    return random;
}
int game(int pc, int you){
    if (pc == you)
        return -1;
    if (pc == 0 && you == 1 || pc == 1 && you == 2 || pc == 2 && you == 0)
        return 0; 
    else if (pc == 0 && you == 2 || pc == 1 && you == 0 || pc == 2 && you == 1)
        return 1;
    return 2;
}
int main(){
    char symbol[3][10] = {"rock","paper","scissor"};
    int a,b,result;
    a=ur_choice();
    if (a>=0){
        b=pc_choice();
        printf ("You choosed : %s\nPC choosed : %s\n",symbol[a],symbol[b]);
        result=game(a,b);
        if (result == -1) {
            printf("Game Draw!\n");
        }
        else if (result == 1) {
            printf("Wow! You have won the game!\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Oh! You have lost the game!\n");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid choice!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to repeat something, you can use a `while` statement.
Hence, you can assign a value to your variable `a` and check whether it returns `-1` or not at the same time using this syntax.

```c
while ((a = ur_choice()) != -1) {
  // game's content
}
```

Comment: But be wary: unless other changes are made, this will not work well interactively.  (The 2nd call to getchar() is likely to return `'\n'`)

Comment: any way to stop that? or any alternative method for  getchar();